# suffix tree construction

Tags: c++, suffix-tree

i am going to implement  suffix tree for given string, i think   it should  delcared like this

```
struct suffix
{

char  letter;
suffix * left,*right; 

};
suffix *insert(suffix *node,char *s){

}
```

//here i am going to  construct tree with all occurances of substrings and characters
but dont know how use  left and right part,is  this  tree  sorted and arranged by strict ordering of characters like binary search tree?or?please help me ,i dont want  to use  some code on online,i need to implement it myselft,so  please give me some hints,some little code

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the [Wikipedia description](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree):

[image: Suffix tree]

Note, first of all, that a suffix tree is not a binary tree so your implementation outline is fundamentally flawed.

Next, it’s not enough to store a single character per node / branch; a suffix tree branch represents a *substring* which can be longer than a single character. It’s also usual to store just the start and end indices of the substring within the string, and not the string itself; otherwise the suffix tree would consume a lot of unnecessary memory.

Lastly, [don’t use pointers](https://twitter.com/#!/klmr/status/177173159836008448) here. They buy you nothing and only cause trouble. Use something like a `boost::container::vector<suffix>` instead (I’d suggest a `std::vector<suffix>`, but unfortunately [standard library containers cannot deal with incomplete types](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18672135/1968)).

Comment: so it means that  i should use loop  in insert method?one loop for   entire string,another loop for looking all subsequent  substring and add it to node?

Comment: @dato Well you certainly won’t get around a loop.

Comment: sorry for  reply later,because i was out of home,when i create  vector<suffix>i can't access  content of  structure why?for example in struct suffix i declared  string s,how can i access this  string?

Comment: There is way too little information in your comment to answer this. Open a new question with the specific problem.

Answer (score 4):

The wikipedia is a start.

However actually doing it is to understand the suffix tree construction algorithm, the Weiner or the Ukkonen algorithm.

The Ukkonen algorithm is simpler:
http://europa.zbh.uni-hamburg.de/pubs/pdf/GieKur1997.pdf

Also this link is less academic and more practical:
http://www.cise.ufl.edu/~sahni/dsaaj/enrich/c16/suffix.htm

Try to start understanding the algorithm.

After that good luck, this is one of the toughest data structures. The only thing worst is the compressed and optimized versions of the suffix tree.

But all great programmers like big challenges.