# The order in which to declare objects and using typedef in C++

Tags: c++, typedef, declaration, predicate

Consider a class A, STL container B and a binary predicate C for the container.

Container B is used in class A. But class A is also used in the binary predicate C.

```
struct C{
  bool operator()(A const &a, A const &b){
    return a.compare_variable < b.compare_variable;
  }
};
```

We need this predicate in order to define the container, which uses it to order its elements.

Because the container declaration becomes rather long, I used typedef to simplify the declaration.

```
typedef B<A, vector<A>, C> type;
```

Finally, my goal is to declare the container B ---whose declaration is abbreviated to "type" --- inside the class A. Namely, as a static public member variable.

```
class A{
  public:
  type container1, container2;
};
```

What is the right order is which to declare A, B and C?

I tried the following variations in the order:

- first declaring the class A, then the struct C and at last the typedef, I get the error that container1, container2 do not name a type --- type did not exist at the time of the class declaration;
- first the typedef: loads of errors --- both the class and struct are not defined yet;
- first declaring the class, with the typedef in the public: section the the struct: an error saying that the third template argument (C) is invalid --- it has not been defined yet;
- first declaring the struct: error saying the the class is not defined yet.

Is the method that I use unnecessarily cumbersome and does there exist a more elegant solution?

Comment: There is a typo mistake in bool operator() definition it should be  `bool operator()(A const &a, A const &b) {...`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Important caveat**: Standard library containers like `std::vector` technically [do not support incomplete types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18672135/why-c-containers-dont-allow-incomplete-types). Instantiating them with an incomplete type is undefined behavior. The type `A` is incomplete in the definition of `A`,  which means that you can't reliably use, for example, a member of type `std::vector<A>` in the definition of `A`. Thus, you'd want to use something like [one of Boost's containers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/container/main_features.html#container.main_features.containers_of_incomplete_types) that has guaranteed support for incomplete types.

**The below discussion assumes that `B` and `vector` support instantiation with incomplete types.** If they don't, it would be impossible to do what you are trying to do.

---

First, figure out the dependencies:

```
struct C {
  bool operator()(A const &a, A const &b){
    return a.compare_variable < b.compare_variable;
  }
};
```

Defining `C` itself, including *declaring* `C::operator()`, only requires `A` to be forward-declared. However, *defining* `C::operator()` requires the full definition of `A`, because the function body references a member of `A`.

```
typedef B<A, vector<A>, C> type;
```

Defining `type` merely requires `A`, `vector`, `B`, and `C` to be forward-declared. A typedef by itself doesn't trigger instantiation of the templates.

```
class A{
public:
    type container1, container2;
};
```

This triggers the instantiation of `B<A, vector<A>, C>`, requiring the full definition of `B`. Containers are likely to also require `C`, the comparator, to be a complete type, since they need to store a copy of it.

So, in short:

- Defining `C` requires a forward declaration of `A`. Defining `C::operator()` requires the full definition of `A`.
- Defining `type` requires the forward declaration of `A`, `B` and `C`.
- Defining `A` requires the full definition of `B` and `C`.

Once you've sorted out the dependencies, you can write the code. Assuming `B` is defined by including the appropriate header:

```
class A;     // Forward declare A for C's definition
struct C {
  bool operator()(A const &a, A const &b);
};

typedef B<A, vector<A>, C> type;

class A{
public:
    type container1, container2;
};

inline bool C::operator()(A const &a, A const &b){
  return a.compare_variable < b.compare_variable;
}
```

Note that you need to actually make a `compare_variable` member in A, obviously.

Comment: So ``inline`` is used to substitute the function code at each call site. This makes sense for a comparison operation. Are there, however, also other kinds of functions for which we would require ``inline``?

Comment: @MusséRedi The `inline` specifier basically allows you to put the function definition inside a header file without getting a linker error. Compilers these days generally decide for themselves whether to actually inline a function. Note that any function defined inside a class definition (like `operator()` in your original `C`) is implicitly `inline`. Since we are moving the function definition outside the class definition, we need to make the `inline` explicit (or define it in a cpp file rather than a header).

Answer (score 1):

So you want something like this?

```
class A {
  struct C{
    bool operator()(A const &, A const &);
  };
  typedef B<A, vector<A>, C> type;
  type c1, c2;

public:
  int compare_variable; // ?
};
// the definition below should either go in a .cpp file,
// or you should mark it inline
bool A::C::operator()(A const &x, A const &y) {
  return x.compare_variable < y.compare_variable;
}
```

Comment: What is the preferred convention in this case? To me, it seems logical and more elegant to include the comparison predicate C inside the class, just as you did, instead of declaring it a separate struct.

Comment: If it's logically bound to the class, put it in there. If you might plausibly re-use it, put it outside.