# C++ export template implementation of incomplete type

Tags: c++, templates, forward-declaration

I have the following scenario:

> header.h:

```
class A
{
    public:

    class B; // incomplete type

private:
    // is never used outside of source file for A
    std::vector<B> vector_of_bs; // template
}
```

> source1.cpp:

```
class A::B {}; // defined here
```

All is good until here. Now if I want to use `class A` elsewhere it doesn't work:

`source2.cpp`: uses class A and doesn't compile with

> vector(721): error C2036: 'A::B *' : unknown size
>
> while compiling class template member function 'std::vector<_Ty> &std::vector<_Ty>::operator =(const std::vector<_Ty> &)'

in VS2010. How can I link against the template specialisation of std::vector in source1.o?

I also need to use this with `declspec(_dllimport)`...

Answer (score 2):

Standard library containers [cannot be instantiated with incomplete types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18672135/why-c-containers-dont-allow-incomplete-types). To do so is undefined behaviour, and in your case produces a clear error. Other implementations would silently accept your code.

To address this issue, boost provides [counterparts for the standard library containers that can in fact be instantiated with incomplete types](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/container/main_features.html#container.main_features.containers_of_incomplete_types). You could replace `std::vector` with the boost counterpart to fix your code:

```
#include <boost/container/vector.hpp>

class A
{
 public: 
    class B; // incomplete type

 private:
    boost::vector<B> vector_of_bs;
};
```

Comment: I don't think that's sufficient. `B` will have to be complete when the copy assignment/destructor/copy constructor etc. are generated, so you'd probably need explicit declarations in the class definition, followed by explicit defaulting in the source file where `B` is complete, similar to pimpls with `unique_ptr`.