# Define class with fields from the type of the class

Tags: c++, class, c++11, vector

Can someone explain me why I can't define something like that:

```
Class A {  
A a;
//...
};
```

But I can define something like that:

```
Class A {  
std::vector<A> vec;
//...
};
```

What is the difference that allow the second?

Comment: Try calculating size of the objects of class `A` (hint `vector` typically stores just several pointers)

Comment: The second one isn't allowed in standard C++ either.

Comment: @juanchopanza Why is that?

Comment: @juanchopanza It's similar to `Class A { A* somePtr; }`

Comment: @Guinzoo Except that the standard says it is undefined behaviour to have containers of incomplete types. Unless that changed in c++17.

Comment: @juanchopanza you right, found some explanaition here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18672135/why-c-containers-dont-allow-incomplete-types

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the first because it is recursive, that is object A contains object A, and the second one you can use because vector doesn't contain object A but a pointer to object A.