# Member STL deque of itself

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, stl, containers

I'm porting to a recent MSVS version the code that somehow compiled in MSVC++ 6:

```
class CTreeNode;

typedef std::deque<CTreeNode> TTreeNodes; 

class CTreeNode {
    // ...
    TTreeNodes   succNodes;
    // ...
};
```

However, in recent MSVC++ this code doesn't compile with `error C2027: use of undefined type 'CTreeNode'` at the line containing `TTreeNodes     succNodes;`.

Any ideas how to change the code least intrusively so to make it to compile?

Comment: You need to use *pointers*. Otherwise you have a structure which contains itself which contains itself which contains itself... And so one in all infinity.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude But a deque uses pointers internally.

Comment: Yup, confirmed failing on MSVC https://godbolt.org/z/KeZzKg

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18672135/why-c-containers-dont-allow-incomplete-types. Boost.container library has a deque that supports incomplete types.

Comment: @interjay That is very implementation-specific (but also very likely). However the deque still need to store `CTreeNode` *objects* inside itself somehow. Usually it keeps a list of arrays of *objects*.

Comment: Something wrong with just declaring `std::deque<CTreeNode> succNodes;` ?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude And then the list inside the deque will store pointers. The deque doesn't store objects directly. As I said above, the Boost.Container library does have containers (including deque) that support recursive types but unfortunately the C++ standard doesn't require this.